# DigitalOcean spaces: metadata settings for cache control

Tags: digital-ocean, digital-ocean-spaces

I am using Spaces from DigitalOcean to serve static assets of a django website. I am running into issues to set the cache policy.

By default no cache policy is set :

[image]

I modified the metadata of my file to add a cache-control setting and I can now see `public,max-age=86400` in the HTTP response :

[image]

However there is still a request being made everytime I refresh or I navigate to a new page :

[image]

The file `all.css` is initally loaded from the fontawesome website and is now in the memory cache while the first four are always loaded from digital ocean.

Here's the response for the file that is cached :

[image]

Here are the settings for metadata in spaces :

[image]

What can I modify to get the caching to work ?